# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, winston

I'm trying to use `Winston` in React.js.

When creating the logger I get the error

> TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

This is how I create it:

```
this.logger = winston.createLogger({
        level: 'info',
        format: winston.format.json(),
        transports: [
          //
          // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
          // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
          //
          new winston.transports.Console(),
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
        ]
      });
```

I only saw questions about how to handle it in Node. How do I solve this issue with React?

Comment: Maybe because `fs` that winston uses is not available in browser side. It's a node js library. To use winston on the browser side i would say try using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-transport-browserconsole

Comment: @AtinSingh should I remove the origianl winston npm package?

Comment: No, you still need winston.

Answer (score 0):

> fs is a nodejs library so you can't use it on browser side. Use winston-transport-browserconsole instead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-transport-browserconsole

It is easy to use and supports logging json objects:

example-

```
import * as winston from "winston";
import BrowserConsole from 'winston-transport-browserconsole';

const level = "debug";
winston.configure({
    transports: [
        new BrowserConsole(
            {
                format: winston.format.simple(),
                level,
            },
        ),
    ],
});

winston.debug("DEBUG ", {a: 1, b: "two"});
```

Comment: What exactly is a browser console transport? Is it persistent?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error that you have. Your vscode might have added a new module to your js file. Remove that module and your app should work just fine.

import { TRUE } from "node-sass"; or import { FALSE } from "node-sass";

just remove the above codes